# Meteor publish not working with limit key

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I've got the following code and it works nicely.

```
Meteor.publish('data_public',function(){
  return DATA_DB.find({},{sort: {published_at: -1}});
})
```

It even reverses order if I changed  `published_at` to `1` instead of `-1`

However when I add a limit keyword (goal is to make to make only the last 10 records available), nothing is available.

```
Meteor.publish('data_public',function(){
  return DATA_DB.find({},{sort: {published_at: 1},limit:10});
})
```

Any thoughts on why this might be?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code.
Can you please try this on your browser's console "DATA_DB.find({}).fetch()".

Comment: You can also check the publication is calling or not from client, by adding some console log in publication.

Comment: @PankajJatav "Uncaught ReferenceError: DATA_DB is not defined(…)"

Comment: Please refresh the page and then try again run "DATA_DB". It should give you an object of mongo